# how do i scan custom attributes from html tags?

Tags: html, regex, xml, tags

how do i scan custom attributes from html tags?
here is example code.
undecided custom attribute name.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td mycustom-attr1="true"></td>
        <td mycustom-attr2="true"></td>
        <td mycustom-attr3="false"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td mycustom-attr1="true"></td>
        <td mycustom-attr2="true"></td>
        <td mycustom-attr3="false"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i want extract to "mycustom-attr1, mycustom-attr2, mycustom-attr3" from this html tag
search for 1000+ jsp pages.

any idia?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: What have you tried? When you extract what exactly do you mean you need to do something with the values? replace the values?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression in most modern languages.

By example :

```
/html/body/table[1]/tr/td/@*[starts-with(name(), 'mycustom')]
```

### OUTPUT

```
 mycustom-attr1="true"
 mycustom-attr2="true"
 mycustom-attr3="false"
```